# Date logic in excel

Tags: vba, date, excel

I am trying to create an automated spreadsheet that will change the date the every week but also keep 2 weeks ahead.

So its a time table where teachers can book out rooms. At the top it displays the what week they are booking for so for example it would say
Week starting 30/3/15 and the on the other sheets it adds on 7 days to the previous weeks time so that it shows 2 weeks in advanced on the other sheets

I'd like to create some logic so that when week 1 is over so id have a date variable that would check if week 1 is over it would then set week 1 to 7 days after week 3 but with my current set up that would then push week 2 and week3 forward by one week which i dont want

can you help me figure out what sort of logic is needed to get this working?

```
Sub SetDate()
Dim Week1 As Date
Dim Week2 As Date
Dim Week3 As Date
Dim Week4 As Date


Week1 = DateValue("30 / 3 / 2015")
Week2 = DateAdd("d", 7, Week1)
Week3 = DateAdd("d", 7, Week2)
Week4 = DateAdd("d", 7, Week3)

Worksheets("Week1").Range("B4").Value = Week1
Worksheets("Week2").Range("B4").Value = Week2
Worksheets("Week3").Range("B4").Value = Week3

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want **Week1** to always be the *Monday* of the current week ??

Comment: that would be the best way yes but since there is 3 sheets for 3 differant weeks it would mean transfering all of that cell data over which is not really viable id like  it to work in a cycle to that when week 1  it will become 7 days after week 3 then when week 2 is over is will become 7 days after week 3 then week 1 will be back to being the oldest week and so on

Comment: it would be allot clearer if i could upload a picture but i don't have enough points

Comment: also ignore the 1 after the week it really isn't relevant it is just to name it different from the other weeks so really they are all just week

Comment: Upload a picture to imgur.com then post the link in your question.

Comment: i would if i could but im on a networked computer so all websites like that are blocked i can barley even get on this sight sometimes

Comment: You have tagged this question with vb.net, but the code looks like vba in Excel. Are you using vb.Net (in Visual Studio) or vba (in Excel)?

Comment: ahh sorry its vba in exvel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question right, but maybe something like this?

Basically, we setup the dates using your original date, then we check to see if any date is before that time - if so, we increment it and check again. That way, if we need to cycle a few weeks, it will keep cycling until they're all current?

Please give it a shot and let me know if this isn't what you need and I will help you fix it.

I tested it by setting the dates to 3/30/2015, 4/6/2015, and 4/13/2015

Week1 becomes 4/20/2015 and the others remain the same (which I believe is as intended). If we roll the weeks back so that 2 have passed (shouldn't happen in practice), you will get the same offsets date wise - just all future ones.

```
Sub SetDate()
Dim Week1 As Date
Dim Week2 As Date
Dim Week3 As Date
Dim Week4 As Date

Week1 = Worksheets("Week1").Range("B4").Value
Week2 = Worksheets("Week2").Range("B4").Value
Week3 = Worksheets("Week3").Range("B4").Value

Dim FoundOldDate

Do
FoundOldDate = False
If Week1 - Date < 0 Then
    Week1 = DateAdd("d", 7, Week3)
    FoundOldDate = True
End If
If Week2 - Date < 0 Then
    Week2 = DateAdd("d", 7, Week1)
    FoundOldDate = True
End If
If Week3 - Date < 0 Then
    Week3 = DateAdd("d", 7, Week2)
    FoundOldDate = True
End If
Loop While FoundOldDate

Worksheets("Week1").Range("B4").Value = Week1
Worksheets("Week2").Range("B4").Value = Week2
Worksheets("Week3").Range("B4").Value = Week3

End Sub
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what i needed. ill need to put to the test tho. thanks very much